# Accessing multiple allure reports over http

Tags: jenkins, reporting-services, automation, report, allure

I have test-results in a folder, which will be updated with new executions on every test run.

```
[root@server test-results]# ls -lrt /var/log/test-results/
total 352
drwxrwxrwx. 14 root root 4096 Jan 10 10:28 9ca9cd74-21d3-4d39-b556-1ca914a37408
drwxrwxrwx. 14 root root 4096 Jan 10 10:41 4fc5f9fa-ee03-4370-98bc-0cca6dcb95d6
drwxrwxrwx. 14 root root 4096 Jan 10 13:00 9e7a9239-cbd4-48a1-929e-bf90892903b0
drwxrwxrwx. 14 root root 4096 Jan 11 09:09 544bd6c9-8d43-4e17-bbc7-8395498e98b6
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Jan 14 10:40 faa3284c-01b0-4581-89fd-57a1919d13b7
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Jan 14 11:31 ee84c6f4-048d-4e9d-96c0-2bc4f6ab3f53
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Jan 14 11:46 c229cacb-1e27-4629-a67f-3eb2965006f9
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Jan 14 12:35 2cca5070-0333-4d95-a1e5-c409c3185bf3
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 Jan 14 13:13 e19c3bd1-3a1f-459a-b8f2-5e1bfad11fe9
```

Each of this folder has test-data which can be parsed by the allure engine.

I am trying to find a way to view these results in the following way.

```
https://localhost:port/<test folder name/
https://localhost:port/9ca9cd74-21d3-4d39-b556-1ca914a37408/
https://localhost:port/4fc5f9fa-ee03-4370-98bc-0cca6dcb95d6/
https://localhost:port/9e7a9239-cbd4-48a1-929e-bf90892903b0/
https://localhost:port/544bd6c9-8d43-4e17-bbc7-8395498e98b6/
```

I tried using https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service. This does provide a way to view the allure report. But, it cannot individually allow me to have separate links for different test-results. Instead, it can show allure report of data in only one folder.

I am not sure of the right way to do it. Please let me know if any information is needed.

Comment: Did you find a way to implement this, I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 1):

You can start multiple allure containers using different ports and showing different directories or you can have one directory where you will have all files together.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can handle multiple projects with Allure Docker Service
https://github.com/fescobar/allure-docker-service#MULTIPLE-PROJECTS---REMOTE-REPORTS